# I have a problem with sceneManager.LoadScene

Tags: node.js, .net, unity-game-engine

I have this piece of code

```
                if(personajeCreado == "0")
                {
                Debug.Log("hi");
                UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene("CreandoPersonaje");

                Debug.Log("bye");


                }
```

In the debugger I only read hi, but my scene does not change, there are no errors, there is nothing to indicate a problem. please help.

Comment: Is this in a build on in the editor? If it’s a build. Did you include the scene in the build?

Comment: of course , i tried with numbers, with "name"  building other time, still dont change. it change if i create a variable and put the change in the update but thats not the way i want to do my scripts. In my opinion its a bug.

Comment: It might be, except its working for me, why the node.js tag? can you answer if it was in build? or in the editor?, which version of unity?

Comment: i have a server made with node js communicates with sockets to unity, when i give start in unity as a client i send a message from the server asking if the client is connected (never connected at first) and if not then i change the scene in this case to register. I can see the hi in the console so I know it goes there but the bye doesn't and it doesn't change the scene.

Comment: so this is in the editor not a built version. I cant recreate this issue, if you truly thinhgk you have a bug, log it with unity

Comment: nevermind, when I give it to build and run it does work, but in the editor it doesn't, how awkward to work like that, thank you very much for telling me about build, you gave me the idea to try it by doing build and it worked. Not in the editor, a bit strange, but thanks.

Comment: Where is the rest of your script? And could you add a screenshot of your build settings?

Comment: if i build and run it works so i can work with that ,thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities:
 - You do not have the target scene included in the build
 - The name of the scene is not correct (I would copy the name from the scene file itself)
 - Your target scene is same as your starting scene and you did not notice the change of scene
 - You have error message in your console but you have disabled the error message view and did not see the actual error

Comment: i tried with numbers, with "name"  building other time, still dont change. it change if i create a variable and put the change in the update but thats not the way i want to do my scripts. In my opinion its a bug.